# How can I startx and have it run a script remotely via SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh, x11

I have the following script, which starts X and launches a graphical program:

```
#!/bin/sh
#startGraphics.sh 
#Starts X and runs the graphics program

xinit /opt/common/graphics/bin/launchGraphics.sh &
sleep 10 ; 
echo "Successfully launched graphics program!"
```

I added the sleep and echo because if I simply ran the script, it would kill X and the graphics program immediately as the SSH session closed. The problem is, although the sleep and echo make X and the graphics program start, the SSH session does not end.

*However,* if I manually SSH'd into the machine, then ran the startGraphics.sh script, then exited the SSH session once the X server and program started, they would continue to run, and the SSH session would not hang.

What am I doing wrong here? What is the correct way to do what I am attempting, i.e. how do I start X remotely with the graphics program and have the SSH session complete without hanging and without X immediately terminating?

Though I don't think it relevant to the problem, here is the launchGraphics.sh script, just in case:

```
#!/bin/sh
#launchGraphics.sh
#Starts the graphics program. Requires X to be running
xrandr -s 1920x1050 ;
/opt/common/graphics/bin/graphics --position 0,0 --mode 1 &
/opt/common/graphics/bin/graphics --position 100,0 --mode 2 &
/opt/common/graphics/bin/graphics --position 300,0 --mode 3
```

Comment: This may be due to the child process receiving a signal when the non-interactive session ends. Try using `nohup xinit /opt/common...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be redirection of stdout (and presumably stderr).

By adding > logfile.log 2>&1 & to the end of the xinit line, the SSH session closes out safely and the X session and graphics programs continue to run.

So the final startGraphics.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
#startGraphics.sh 
#Starts X and runs the graphics program

xinit /opt/common/graphics/bin/launchGraphics.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
sleep 10 ; 
echo "Successfully launched graphics program!"
```